# Possible to modify host in headers

Tags: httpd, apache-2.2

Whenever someone visits `intern.old-company-name.example.com` I would like it to get redirected to `https://intern.new-company-name.example.com`. One way to do it would be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://intern.new-company-name.example.com$1
#    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1                                                             
</IfModule>
```

but I don't like that I hardcode the outer sub domain `intern` into the `httpd.conf`.

**Question**

Would it be possible to do a regex on `%{HTTP_HOST}` so `old-company-name` gets replaced with `new-company-name` before the redirection to `https`? Or perhaps something similar?

**Update**

```
# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
10.10.10.10:443     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server a.y.b.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:85)
         port 443 namevhost a.y.b.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:85)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: @ETL From what I can gather the link to point to does not explain how to modify the sub domain part.

Comment: Can we assume that your rewrite rules have `[R]` at the end?  The https rewrite won't create an SSL request any other way and it changes the meaning of the other rewrite rule significantly.

Comment: By the way, it's better to tag your questions with just the tags that are relevant.  Tagging with both [tag:ubuntu] and [tag:centos] is confusing and nothing about this question seems to be [tag:linux] specific.  A [tag:mod-rewrite] tag might have been more appropriate.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes This is doable, but can you give us more of an idea of what the expected inputs to be?  Is it always one subdomain on top of the same parent domain, or are there other scenarios to account for?

Comment: @Ladadadada `[R]` flag is fine. The rule I posted were just my current solution, which I would like to make more generic. I.e. without hardcoding the `intern` sub domain. Hard coding `new-company-name.example.com` is fine.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Yes, the task is to redirect `a.x.b.com` to `https://a.y.b.com` where hard coding `y.b.com` is fine. I would like to avoid `a` being hard coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have the HTTP to HTTPS behavior handled by the HTTP listener, and the old name to new name behavior handled by the HTTPS listener.  (We could have the HTTP redirect also do the name change, but this keeps everything in one place and makes it simpler.)

So, in your main config file we'll put back your original config with a slight tweak:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://${HTTP_HOST}$1
```

Then inside the `<VirtualHost>` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` we'll do the name redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.old-company-name\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.new-company-name.example.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Why is `[R]` needed? Is `L` for security reasons?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes The `R` is implied by the fact that the destination of the rewrite is not the current virtualhost, and the `L` is to ensure that no other `RewriteRule` configuration somewhere else (say, in an `.htaccess` file) is able to fiddle with the redirect before it's sent.

Comment: If I visit `httpS://intern.old-company-name.example.com` then it stays on `old-company-name` instead of redirecting to `httpS://intern.new-company-name.example.com`

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Where are these rules located (virtual host? htaccess file?) - and is that `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` still in place?

Comment: No virtual hosts. I placed it as the bottom of `httpd.conf`, and I still have `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` but if needed it can be changed.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Yeah, remove that - that condition is explicitly preventing the following rule from applying for https requests.

Comment: Even if I do that, then `httpS://a.x.b.com` is for some reason still not redirected to `httpS://a.y.b.com`. The 3 other cases works perfectly.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Actually, just noticed your edit to the answer.  Instead of using this same rule to point from HTTP to HTTPS, we'll need to split them up - one rule for the name correction, and one for the HTTPS redirect.  If that rule were being applied to the `https://a.y.b.com` requests, then the condition would still match and it'd be a redirect loop - so what that tells us is this rule isn't applying to the HTTPS requests at all.  Can you check the output of `apachectl -S`?  There should be a `<VirtualHost>` somewhere since there are both http and https listeners configured.

Comment: Hmm. That sounds very interesting! Updated OP.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Edited answer with a different approach that should work in this case.

Comment: With the new approach both http and https on the old domain does not get redirected, but stays on the domain.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Strange.  Is it redirecting to HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, `http://old...` -> `httpS://old...`, but not afterwards to `httpS://new...`.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes Are the rules inside the `<VirtualHost>` in `ssl.conf`?  And I forgot to mention you'll need a `RewriteEngine On` in that file if there isn't one already, can you check on that?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying headers can be done with mod_headers - check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html for all the syntax and details. I can't say for sure you can acheive what you want - and I'm not sure really why you want to modify the header in this case.